# Google Sheets API Variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm kinda new to coding. I have to make something that submits data from HTML forms to Google sheets. I enabled the API and followed all the steps. Now I'm trying to use the variables firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, and email to allow the input to be submitted upon click of the submit button. I didn't use forms but I'm open to using it if it's needed. Just to clarify again: when you put text into the input boxes, it should append it to a google sheets upon the click of submit. You need a python local server with the port 8000 and run the html file to get it to work.

The problem here is that I'm unable to use the variables (firstName, lastName, email, and phoneNumber) in place of a string in the "values" section in the execute function. Whenever I click the execute button, it appends strings such as "Place_Holder" but when I put in firstName it doesn't append. Sorry for this long explanation. This is my first time posting on here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>googleapi</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Information Form</h1>
    <div>
    <p>First Name:</p>
    <input type="text" id="firstNameInput">
    </div>
    
    <div>
    <p>Last Name:</p>
    <input type="text" id="lastNameInput">
    </div>
    
    <div>
    <p>Email:</p>
    <input type="text" id="emailInput">
    </div> 
    
    <div>
    <p>Phone Number:</p>
    <input type="number" id="phoneNumberInput">
    </div>
    
    <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
<p id="submitMessage"></p>
<script>
document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", displayMessage );
function displayMessage() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById('firstNameInput').value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById('lastNameInput').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('emailInput').value;
    var phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phoneNumberInput').value;
    document.getElementById("submitMessage").innerHTML = "Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName + " your information has been submitted";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for sheets.spreadsheets.values.append
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/sheets/v4/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
</script>
<script>
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
      "spreadsheetId": "*removed*",
      "range": "A1:D2",
      "includeValuesInResponse": "false",
      "insertDataOption": "INSERT_ROWS",
      "responseDateTimeRenderOption": "SERIAL_NUMBER",
      "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED",
      "resource": {
        "values": [
          [
            "Place_Holder",
            "Place_Holder",
            "Place_Holder",
            "Place_Holder"
          ]
        ]
      }
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: '*removed*'});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>

<script src="main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood your situation and what you want to do as follows.

- In your current situation, you can put the string to the spreadsheet using Sheets API.
- You want to put `firstName, lastName, email, and phoneNumber` to the spreadsheet using `append()` of Sheets API.

If my above understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point :

I think that the reason that the variables cannot be put to Sheet is that the variables are not retrieved when `execute()` is run. So when `execute()` is run, it modifies to retrieve the variables.

#### Modified script :

Please modify as follows. When you run this script, please push the execute button on the browser.

From :

```
function execute() {
  return gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    "spreadsheetId": "*removed*",
    "range": "A1:D2",
    "includeValuesInResponse": "false",
    "insertDataOption": "INSERT_ROWS",
    "responseDateTimeRenderOption": "SERIAL_NUMBER",
    "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED",
    "resource": {
      "values": [
        [
          "Place_Holder",
          "Place_Holder",
          "Place_Holder",
          "Place_Holder"
        ]
      ]
    }
  })
```

To :

```
function execute() {
  var firstName = document.getElementById('firstNameInput').value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById('lastNameInput').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('emailInput').value;
  var phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phoneNumberInput').value;
  return gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    "spreadsheetId": "*removed*",
    "range": "A1:D2",
    "includeValuesInResponse": "false",
    "insertDataOption": "INSERT_ROWS",
    "responseDateTimeRenderOption": "SERIAL_NUMBER",
    "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED",
    "resource": {
      "values": [
        [
          firstName,
          lastName,
          email,
          phoneNumber
        ]
      ]
    }
  })
```

#### Note :

- This is a simple modification. So please modify this for your environment.

If I misunderstand your question and this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: @user10152378 Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved.